# Понижает ли мультипроцессорность использование CPU?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, task, pythonanywhere

Вопрос возможно глупый. У меня есть таск на хостинге Pythonanywhere. Он выполняет API запросы на другие ресурсы, а также математические вычисления с полученными данными. У них есть дневные лимиты на использование CPU исчисляемые в секундах. Если я буду использовать библиотеку multiprocessing, разбив свой процесс на несколько процессов, понизит ли это использование CPU секунд?

Comment: От перемены мест слагаемых сумма не меняется

Comment: Думаю даже незначительно увеличите. Может быть Вам на VPS перейти? Они начинаются аш от 55 рублей в месяц...

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а в чем их преимущество?

Comment: Все разобрался, спасибо!